# sqlite with javascript with phonegap using build.phonegap.com for Android

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

build.phonegap.com is something that generates APK file by just taking input from us in html,js,css format . So, we can write code using html,js,css and we can get APK file . They use phonegap library . Currently I am using JSON file as database but I want to use SQLite file as I use ajax to load JSON, when data is big, all will be loaded a time . So trying to migrate to SQLite .

**I can find tutorials to work SQLite with JS , or SQLite with phonegap but wat my doubt is** :

whether I have to use normal JS with SQLite or use phonegap functions to deal with db(as i dont install phonegap library myself) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL storage functions exposed through the Cordova / PhoneGap API are based on the W3C specification for Web SQL Databases, and as such dont really differ from the functionality you would get from 'standard' JS database functions.

You should just be able to write your database interaction calls using the code like the examples shown on the PhoneGap Documentation page http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

It shouldn't matter that you're using the PhoneGap build service.

If this isn't the answer you were looking for, or I misinterpreted your question I apologise. If so, can you clarify your question a little more so that we can help you?

Many thanks